# Unable to connect to SQL Server using SqlConnection (but OK with OleDbConnection)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlconnection, oledbconnection

I have a SQL Server 2008 instance running on Amazon RDS and another test database server running as a SQL 2008 Express installation on an Amazon EC2 instance.

I am able to connect to both of these servers using SQL Server Management Studio (and other tools like Navicat) so, I am happy that the servers are correctly configured to accept remote TCP connections and that there are no firewall issues.

However, when I try to establish a connection from a C# application, using `SqlConnection`, it fails with a timeout. But, if I try the same experiment using an `OleDbConnection` it works fine (after adjusting the connection string to include the provider information).

For comparison, if I run the experiment on the EC2 instance, using an `SqlConnection` with a connection string that establishes a `(local)` connection, it also works correctly, so I assume the issue is related to the use of `SqlConnection` remotely.

Does anyone have any idea what I need to do to get `SqlConnection` working, or what steps I could take to further diagnose the cause of the problem?

Many thanks for your advice,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this behavior is caused by [this issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729323) and, in my case, it was specifically because my PCTools firewall was doing something unexpected with the outbound TCP packets created by `SqlConnection`.

I implemented a temporary workaround by uninstalling PCTools (it was not sufficient to merely disable the firewall), so I now have to find a new firewall that complies with what Windows/SQL Client is expecting.